# codeigniter 404 not found CSS

Tags: codeigniter

I have an issue about CSS url in codeigniter:

In file controllers I have the file `admin/home.php`

in home.php :

```
class Home have function index() and function login().
function login() { redirect('admin/home');}
```

file config:

```
$routes['admin'] = 'admin/home/login';
$routes['admin/home'] = 'admin/home/index';
```

and error:

```
Request URL:http://congnghehatnhan.tk/admin/public/css/bootstrap.min.css

Request Method:GET

Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Comment: It is probably because the bootstrap.min.css doesn't exsists or its in another location. Check if the css is in that location where the script expects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have the following syntax when describing your site assets:

```
<link href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your problem occurs when you are on the following URL:

```
http://congnghehatnhan.tk/admin/
```

A side-effect of using the stylesheet declaration directly as you have, results in the fact that the stylesheet is currently linking to:

```
http://congnghehatnhan.tk/admin/public/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

You however want it to link to:

```
http://congnghehatnhan.tk/public/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

*Notice the missing **admin** segment from the URL.*

When referencing assets via CodeIgniter, you want to use the base_url() method in order to generate the correct link. Thus, without knowing more about your codebase, I believe that changing the original stylesheet declaration to the following should fix your issue:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('public/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please note that the approach above applies to all instances of referencing assets.

Comment: thanks you, Petre! you can share about base_url() and site_url() different?

Comment: Hey @quandev.vn, base_url() will generate a URL for assets (i.e. base_url('test.css') = localhost/test.css), while site_url() will generate a URL for controller actions (i.e. site_url('product/listing') = localhost/index.php/product/listing); If you removed index.php from your URLs, then they will behave the same, however I would keep their intended purpose, if mostly just as a best practice.