# php Codeigniter - CSS wont load

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter project files, the css files are in same subdirectory, so the `index.html`'s code on header like below :

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but CSS wont'load and after right click and view source then **click css link**,i found this source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>404 Page Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
        <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone explain what happen to my code ?

Comment: it seems problem with your routes

Comment: what is the permission of css files ?

Comment: You must have .htaccess file with rules defined to redirect to index.php Check that, may be your problem gets solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072479/where-should-someone-put-the-static-files-such-as-cs-js-and-images-in-the-codei

Comment: @vishal permission is ok, all files are in windows sys

Comment: @DharanBro could you explain more, what's the problem ?

Comment: Could you provide the link that you are trying to open in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, after change all linking to CSS :

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and change `config.php` to :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cidlab';
```

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332068/codeigniter-404-not-found-css)
and Thanks to Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to use URLs relative to domain instead of relative to page.

```
<link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Also follow the best practices of serving static assets like CSS, Images, Scripts:

- [Codeigniter assets folder best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice)
- [Where should someone put the static files such as CS, JS and images in the Codeigniter folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072479/where-should-someone-put-the-static-files-such-as-cs-js-and-images-in-the-codei)

Comment: One may have to consider directory structure I suppose..This may not help.. _Depends_

Comment: @RayonDabre Agreed. If the OP could reply, I would be glad to help. But he's long gone! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar before i move the css file to same sub directory as view, the css was in subdirectory like you said before. in public/css, that's way i moved it, but still face error...